# Bottom to Up pop up through Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, mobile-application

I am developing an iOS mobile application using swift. I  have to make a pop up which will slide down to up. Is there any simple way to implement it programatically.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: :Heard of model segue ? Which in storyboard u see as present modally tried exploring it a bit ? If not consider doing so. This site won't provide u code. No thats not how it work. You tell us what u tried and where u stuck will help u with it

Comment: We are using this code, 
let LogoutVC = LogoutViewController(nibName: "LogoutViewController", bundle: nil)
self.addChildViewController(LogoutVC)
LogoutVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(LogoutVC.view)
LogoutVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

How can we set direction of popup?